# 8086 Assembly keyboard ISR implementation

Tags: assembly, keyboard, interrupt, x86-16, isr

I can't understand why the keyboard interrupt service routine I wrote for my program (should print "hello world" each time I press a key) only occurs once when I execute the .exe on dosbox.
Here is the code:

```
  NAME keyb

PILE    SEGMENT STACK
    db      20 dup ('LA PILE ')
PILE    ENDS


DONNEE SEGMENT
message db "Hello wolrd !$"
DONNEE ENDS

PROGRAMME SEGMENT
ASSUME CS:PROGRAMME , DS:DONNEE, ES:NOTHING, SS:PILE
debut:

    mov ax,DONNEE
    mov ds,ax

    cli

    xor ax,ax
    mov es, ax ; load ES with segment address of interrupt pointer table
    mov bx, 24h ; load BX with interrupt type
    mov word ptr es:[bx], OFFSET SUBR ; isr address
    mov word ptr es:[bx]+2, SEG SUBR ; isr segment
    mov ax, 01h
    sti

BOUCLE: jmp BOUCLE

SUBR PROC NEAR
    cli
    mov ah,9
    mov dx,OFFSET message
    int 21h
    sti

    IRET
SUBR ENDP

PROGRAMME ENDS

    END debut
```

I tried a few things, like push-ing and pop-ing registers, using another interrupt (system clock 08h), but none of them worked. 
I know that the ISR runs at least once because the message "hello world" appears on screen, but it should print every time I press a key and I have no idea why it doesn't.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do some work to "free" keyboard and interrupt. Take a look [here](http://webpages.charter.net/danrollins/techhelp/0106.HTM). The easiest way is to jump to the old IRQ-handler at the end of your own handler:

```
NAME keyb

PILE    SEGMENT STACK
    db      20 dup ('LA PILE ')
PILE    ENDS

DONNEE SEGMENT
message db "Hello wolrd !$"
oldvec dw 0, 0
DONNEE ENDS

PROGRAMME SEGMENT
ASSUME CS:PROGRAMME , DS:DONNEE, ES:NOTHING, SS:PILE
debut:

    mov ax,DONNEE
    mov ds,ax

    cli

    xor ax,ax
    mov es, ax ; load ES with segment address of interrupt pointer table
    mov bx, 24h ; load BX with interrupt type

    ; Store the old IRQ vector
    mov ax, es:[bx]
    mov oldvec, ax
    mov ax, es:[bx+2]
    mov oldvec + 2, ax

    mov word ptr es:[bx], OFFSET SUBR ; isr address
    mov word ptr es:[bx]+2, SEG SUBR ; isr segment
    mov ax, 01h
    sti

BOUCLE: jmp BOUCLE

SUBR PROC NEAR
    push ax
    push dx

    mov ah,9
    mov dx,OFFSET message
    int 21h

    pop dx
    pop ax    

    jmp dword ptr [oldvec]
SUBR ENDP

PROGRAMME ENDS

END debut
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically put, unless you call the default handler after you've done your work, you'll have to tell the PIC (programmable interrupt controller) that you're done - the default handler will do this for you - sending the EOI (end of interrupt signal) to the PIC(s). **The PIC wont fire the interrupt again until you tell it that you've done with the current one.**

Code to do this in 32 bit protected mode looks something like this. Do note, that I use a generic handler for all IRQs, just handing off to the appropriately registered user callback function. I've included both.

First, the generic IRQ handler

```
irq_handler:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    add     ebp, 8


    mov     eax, [ebp +registers_t.int_no]

    cmp     eax, IRQ7                   ; this just dumps spurious IRQ7 interrupts
    je      .irqHandlerDone

    cmp     eax, IRQ8                   ; if it's IRQ0 - IRQ7, the first controller fired the int, otherwise the slave controller did
    jb      .slaveResetDone
.resetSlave:
    mov     al,20H      ; send End-Of-Interrupt signal
    out     0xA0,al     ; to the 8259 _slave_ Programmable Interrupt Controller
.slaveResetDone:
.resetMaster:
    mov     al, 0x20    ; send End-Of-Interrupt signal
    out     0x20, al    ; to the 8259 master Programmable Interrupt Controller

    mov     eax, [ebp + registers_t.int_no]
    shl     eax, 2                              ; x4
    mov     esi, interrupt_handlers
    add     esi, eax                            ; esi --> interrupt_handlers[int_no]
    cmp     dword [esi], 0
    je      .irqHandlerDone

    call    [esi]
.irqHandlerDone:
    pop     ebp
    ret
```

Next, the IRQ1 (keyboard) handler. The registration function simply copies the offset of the function into a table (`interrupt_handlers`) of 32 bit addresses.
I'm in flat-memory mode (4GB addressable, ES already holds the segment selector for a writeable data segment. 0xB8000 + 79*2 simply points to the character on the top-right of a 80x25 mode3 text screen)

```
; keyboard IRQ handler
irq1Handler:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    add     ebp, 8+4

    in      al, 0x60
    mov     bl, al
    mov     byte [port60], al

    in      al, 0x61
    mov     ah, al
    or      al, 0x80
    out     0x61, al
    xchg    ah, al
    out     0x61, al

    and     bl, 0x80
    jnz     .done

    pusha
    ;mov        al, [port60]
    ;call   outputChar

    mov     edi, 0xB8000 + 79*2
    mov     al, [port60]
    mov     [es:edi], al

    popa
.done:  
    pop     ebp
    ret
port60  db  0
```

The code draws from James M's tutorial, here: http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/5.-IRQs%20and%20the%20PIT.html

There is much that can be read about interfacing to hardware over at OSDev.org - http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page

**UPDATE:**
Here's a 16bit ISR that functions in DosBox.

```
;-----------------------------------------------------
; handles int 0x09
;-----------------------------------------------------
keyhandler:
    cli
    pusha
    in al, 0x60                     ; get key data
    mov bl, al                      ; save it
    mov byte [port60], al

    in al, 0x61                     ; keybrd control
    mov ah, al
    or al, 0x80                     ; disable bit 7
    out 0x61, al                    ; send it back
    xchg ah, al                     ; get original
    out 0x61, al                    ; send that back

    mov al, 0x20                    ; End of Interrupt
    out 0x20, al                    ;

    and bl, 0x80                    ; key released
    jnz done                        ; don't repeat

    mov al, [port60]
    ;
    ; do something with the scan-code here
    ;
done:
    popa
    iret
port60    db    0        ; where we'll store the scan-code
```